# Вывод ноды в drupal7

Tags: drupal

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вывести ноду в `drupal7`

Например, у меня есть страница с контактной информацией, я подключил модуль contact форма обратной связи появилась по адресу
http://test1.ru/site/contact
теперь я хотел бы встроить ноду, на которой форма контактов в страницу, на которой контактная информация

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более сложный вариант использовать модуль [panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels)
Но зато потом можно будет навесить ещё много на ноду или в панель...

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте блок с контактами на страницу с формой контактов.